# Compile java app to php plugin

Tags: java, php, yii, ant

First of all, I must mention that I don't know java. I'm php developer. But I got a task where I need to download validator written on JAVA. Should be compiled and added as a separate YII module with php-wrapper. Source is [here](https://github.com/skynav/ttv). I have no idea how to do this, and I couldn't find anything that helps. Also when I try to compile this validator I get an error `BUILD FAILED ${env.CATALINA_HOME}/lib does not exist`. I try to compile it with `ant build` as it says in manual. So, can anybody please help me with this? Thanks in advance

EDIT: I managed to build. Problem was in path for `CATALINA_HOME`. So that's solved. Anybody has any idea about wrapping this to PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re: wrapping your Java plugin in PHP, your best bet will probably be to call the Java plugin on the command line.

I would build a Yii validator class which internally does the command line call with the parameters passed to it as it is setup.

That should work for you.

Comment: I thought so. I'll try definitely that, and let you know results. Thanks!:)

Comment: @MrCkobe Glad to hear it :-)